# JSON serialization double quote (") and single (') quote issue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, object, nsutf8encoding

I'm facing JSON encoding issue.

I have submitted my data to server on below formate to save remarks.

```
{
Remarks = "test apple """ ";
}
```

Then while fetching the data from the server, I'm receiving different formate like 
output:

```
{
Remarks = "test apple \U00e2\U0080\U009c\U00e2\U0080\U009d\U00e2\U0080\U009d\U00e2\U0080\U009d\\n";
}
```

While submitting data I'm using JSON serialisation.

```
  NSData *jsonData
    = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: dict
                                      options: NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                        error: nil];

  if (jsonData)
  {
    NSString* jsonString
      = [[NSString alloc]
          initWithData: jsonData
              encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"posting params: %@", jsonString);
  }
```

My question is why I'm not getting I have submitted. I'm facing only double quote (") and single (') symbols.

Any one have idea?

Comment: Can you show some server code?

Comment: Android application is working fine..

Comment: Only iOS only facing.. do you have any idea @André Slotta?

Comment: In your example there are only double quotes, correct? How do you send the data to the server. Is the example a part of your code?

Comment: @Amin Negm-Awad yes

Comment: To both questions? If it is an example from Objective-C code, there should be an error.

Comment: But I'm able to submit the data to server..

Comment: I found something..  iOS 11 default quotation mark changed to ‘ ’ and “ ”

Comment: There is no default quotation mark in iOS. The default quotation marks in Objective-C are `@"` (opening) and `"` (closing). In Objective-C your code, if it is a string literal, makes no sense. Therefore please post the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 11 has added "Smart Punctuation" to the keyboard settings.

This means when typing "Singapore" it will convert it to “Singapore”. The '"' are replaced by a '“' and '”' string. Those are different quotes.

So one option might be to also replace '“' and '”' by '\"'.

```
Smart Punctuation = No
```

Comment: Hi how to handle my code i am facing same issue with double quote :
[{"fontFamily"="firstfont","fontURL"="https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2FAttachments%2F1295312%2FUmbrellaMarket.ttf%3FAWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIBQXWGUYOJ6RIHHA&Expires=1853589442&Signature=fY8146gswIkXYyuouOT90HPbOlA%253D"},{"fontFamily"="secondfont","fontURL"="https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fttachments%2F1295312%2FUmbrellaMarket.ttf%3FAWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIBQXWGUYOJ6RIHHA&Expires=1853589460&Signature=LKw3TMt9r9BPC9zmiw85tTktX1A%253D"}]

Comment: when i am sending this code to server then i am getting error

Answer (score 0):

You probably should escape your non-delimitating quotes :
{
    Remarks = "test apple \"\"\" ";
}

Comment: Likely, but as long as he is not quoting his whole code, it is guessing.